# SQL query written in 2008 does not work in 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I wrote a trigger in the development environment which runs `SQL Server 2008`. I then tried to execute it in production, which runs `SQL Server 2005`.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trg_issues_update, Line 97
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

The query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, surname, pwd, emailaddress, resetpwd, comment,  apikey, active)
VALUES (@username, @first_name, @last_name, @password, @email, NULL, 'Comment: ' + CAST(@issueid AS VARCHAR), 'None', '1');
```

**UPDATE**: This is the part of the trigger where most of the variables are declared/set:

```
IF (SELECT projectid FROM inserted) = 55 AND (SELECT issuestatusid FROM inserted) = 28 BEGIN
    DECLARE @full_name nvarchar (255)
    SET @full_name = (SELECT fielddata FROM customfielddata WHERE issueid = @issueid AND customfieldid = 84)

    DECLARE @first_name nvarchar (255)
    SET @first_name = SUBSTRING(@full_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @full_name) - 1)

    DECLARE @last_name nvarchar (255)
    SET @last_name = SUBSTRING(@full_name, CHARINDEX(' ', @full_name) + 1, LEN(@full_name) + 1)

    DECLARE @email nvarchar (255)
    SET @email = (SELECT fielddata FROM customfielddata WHERE issueid = @issueid AND customfieldid = 85)

    DECLARE @location nvarchar (255)
    DECLARE @domain nvarchar (255)
    DECLARE @username nvarchar (255)
    SET @location = (SELECT fielddata FROM customfielddata WHERE issueid = @issueid AND customfieldid = 86)
    SET @domain = (SELECT fielddata FROM customfielddata WHERE issueid = @issueid AND customfieldid = 87)
    IF @location = 'Canada' BEGIN SET @username = 'ORG1\' + UPPER(@domain) END
    ELSE SET @username = 'ORG2\' + UPPER(@domain)

    DECLARE @password binary (16)
    SET @password = CONVERT(BINARY(16), HashBytes('MD5', ''), 2)

    DECLARE @comment nvarchar (500)
    SET @comment = 'APPR-' + CAST(@issueid AS VARCHAR)

    INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, surname, pwd, emailaddress, resetpwd, comment, apikey, active)
    VALUES (@username, @first_name, @last_name, @password, @email, NULL, @comment, 'None', '1');

    DECLARE @userid NUMERIC(10,0)
    SET @userid = (SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = @username)

    INSERT INTO globalgroupmembership (globalgroupid, userid, created)
    VALUES (1, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), (3, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

END
```

I assume it's because of the 2005 vs 2008 differences, but can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Can you share the whole `trg_issues_update` ?

Comment: Ya - we'll need to see the trigger to help you, since that's where the error is

Comment: The issue is with this line `VALUES (1, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), (3, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` 2005 doesn't support the `VALUES(etc), (etc)`  For that line, use either multiple `INSERT` statements or `SELECT` with `UNION ALL`

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet - I re-wrote that part and the query executed successfully. Feel free to post an answer, I will accept it. Line 97 from the error message was that INSERT query I posted originally, oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the line:

```
INSERT INTO globalgroupmembership (globalgroupid, userid, created)
VALUES (1, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), (3, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

From [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> SQL Server 2008 introduces the Transact-SQL row constructor (also called a table value constructor) to specify multiple rows in a single INSERT statement. The row constructor consists of a single VALUES clause with multiple value lists enclosed in parentheses and separated by a comma.

In order to fix this so it will work in both SQL 2008 and SQL Server 2005, you will want to rewrite the query to:

```
INSERT INTO globalgroupmembership (globalgroupid, userid, created)
VALUES (1, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO globalgroupmembership (globalgroupid, userid, created)
VALUES (3, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Or you can use `INSERT INTO... SELECT...UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO globalgroupmembership (globalgroupid, userid, created)
SELECT 1, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, @userid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score -2):

try to concatinate the comment before the value list:

```
declare @comment varchar
set @comment = 'Comment: ' + cast(@issueid as varchar)

INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, surname, pwd, emailaddress, resetpwd, comment,  apikey, active)
select @username, @first_name, @last_name, @password, @email, NULL, @comment, 'None', '1'
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I guess it's because 2005 supports expressions in the values part of an insert.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it didn't work unfortunately (it wasn't me who downvoted).